# Seek C/C++ library to solve linear regression problem

Tags: optimization, c++, library

Is there some off-the-shelf C/C++ library to solve the following problem:

[image]

Comment: This is not a linear regression problem. This is a ridge regression problem. If you change your question to 'How to solve the ridge regression problem?' you will likely get [many](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/13561/603) [good](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/20303/603) [answers](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/118712/why-does-ridge-estimate-become-better-than-ols-by-adding-a-constant-to-the-diago/119708#119708) on cross validated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure about the particular formula you've referred to, but you have an extremely wide variety of libraries to choose from for regression, optimization and other numerical solutions: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_numerical_libraries (see C, C++ and multi-language sections). In addition, take a look at IMHO very interesting [Accord.NET framework](http://accord-framework.net), which offers this functionality and much more. Hope this helps.